# Why does this NASM assembly program print nothing

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I have the following assembly, which I assemble with NASM and then link with gcc:

```
section .text
extern printf
global main
main:
    sub rsp, 8 ;align stack pointer
    mov rax, 0 ;no vector arguments
    mov rdi, intro_message ;First argument
    call printf
    mov rax, 60 ;exit
    syscall
section .data
intro_message:
    db 'Hello world',0
```

When I run ./a.out, nothing is printed, and the instruction pointer seems to have moved to an invalid location. What have I done wrong?

Comment: standard output is line buffered and you used a raw exit syscall so the C library didn't have a chance to shut down properly and flush the buffer. Preferably do `call exit`.

Comment: @Jester - This was indeed the issue - if only I could accept comments as best answer ;)

Comment: @user3519580 If you use the libc, you should as a rule of thumb  never do system calls directly. Always call into the libc to do system calls!